# 'SelectInput' get both selected ID and NAME key value and assign to separate key

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using admin on rest create form. I have field to select 'category'.

```
<SelectInput source="category" choices={[
    { id: '1', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Photography' },
]} />
```

Here, When select 'category' I knew that 'id' value will be assigned to source 'category' key. But I wanted When select 'category' that 'name' value also must be assigned in 'category_name' key separately. So finally I wanted to pass both selected 'category' and 'category_name' also. How to achieve this?

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a custom input for that: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component

Comment: Thnks @Gildas. Still I am confused. When I select option from above given drop-down, I need to assign selected value to separate keys. Example: {category:1, categoryName: 'Programming'}. Then after submit form, Need to send those value to back-end API. How to achieve this. If you post sample example, it would be more helpful. I am trying this past two days. But I could not get any solution.